# (Python) Using DictVectoriser from sklearn class with strings

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Apologies in advance for what I expect will be a simple question/answer. New to python and sklearn here. I have a variable (pandas data frame column) which is a list of unicode strings. I want to use the `DictVectorizer` class from sklearn to unpack this into one-hot-encoded matrix where each column is one of the possible string values and each value in the matrix is a binary value indicating whether that value was present in that list.

The example in the `DictVectorizer` docs is as follows:

```py
# example from docs from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer 
v = DictVectorizer(sparse=False) 
D = [{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}, {'foo': 3, 'baz': 1}] 
X = v.fit_transform(D) 
X
```

And this returns the vectorised array as promised but in my case I want to pass it a list of unicode strings eg:

```py
# my case
D = [[u"foo", u"bar"], [u"foo"]]
X = v.fit_transform(D)
```

and here I get an error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-6a41384fcd8f> in <module>()
      1 # my case
      2 D = [[u"foo", u"bar"], [u"foo"]]
----> 3 X = v.fit_transform(D)

/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.pyc in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    224             Feature vectors; always 2-d.
    225         """
--> 226         return self._transform(X, fitting=True)
    227 
    228     def inverse_transform(self, X, dict_type=dict):

/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.pyc in _transform(self, X, fitting)
    160         # same time
    161         for x in X:
--> 162             for f, v in six.iteritems(x):
    163                 if isinstance(v, six.string_types):
    164                     f = "%s%s%s" % (f, self.separator, v)

/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/six.pyc in iteritems(d, **kw)
    437 def iteritems(d, **kw):
    438     """Return an iterator over the (key, value) pairs of a dictionary."""
--> 439     return iter(getattr(d, _iteritems)(**kw))
    440 
    441 def iterlists(d, **kw):

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: error is clear you're trying to use a dict vectoriser on a list of lists so you need to convert the type

Comment: thanks @EdChum would you mind helping me a little further with how to convert the type?

Comment: The docs state you need to pass a dict where the keys are your strings and the values are the index positions, presumably you can pass a Series of your strings but it's unclear what form your data really is

Answer (score 1):

@EdChum's response helped me to figure out the problem. I think the following might fix the problem.

```
from collections import Counter
D = [[u"foo", u"bar"], [u"foo"]]
q = dict(Counter(x for xs in D for x in set(xs)))
X = v.fit_transform(q)
```

I am changing the type to what `fit_transform` expects .i.e., a `dictionary`. I know its late but since this thread opens up with high priority on "DictVectorizer fit_transform" search results, I thought it might help somebody. If possible, please comment if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments and @Muthu's answer, the input format for `DictVectorizer` is dict.

If you the count of the elements use `Counter` else if you need it as one hot encoding, use `set` in the `lambda` function.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

D = [[u"foo", u"bar"], [u"foo"]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_col': D})

x = df['my_col'].apply(lambda x: dict(Counter(x)))
DictVectorizer(sparse=False).fit_transform(x)

#array([[1., 1.],
#       [0., 1.]])
```